# Strange behaviour of my code with strtotime

Tags: php, datepicker

I'm having some headaches with dates in PHP. I'm getting some data from a form and trying to "submit" it with an ajax call to update the web without reloading the page.

I have a datepicker which allows to pick a range of dates and so, I've done a dirty function to separate the start and the end date and posting it to PHP separately (in case a range of dates where selected). They are formated in this way: 01/04/2011,08/04/2011

In the PHP so I have the dates variables and try to format them to perform some database queries in this ways:

```
$date_start = $_POST['date_start'];
$date_start_form = date("Y-m-d",  strtotime($date_start));
```

After some testing I have discovered that if the date is higher to day 12 of whichever month, and then try to format it, it gives me back 1970-01-01.

Does someone know why this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, the way to solve the problem is to not use / as the date separator, if - or . is used like 08.04.2011 or 08-04-2011, then the European method will be assumed to be in use.

If you can only receive dates in 08/04/2011 format, then a simple str_replace will take care of it:

```
$date = "08/04/2011";
$date = str_replace('/','.',$date); //08.04.2011
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));  //2011-04-08
```

Comment: Nice! This SOLVEs the issue :D

Comment: Welcome, it would be better if you modified whatever is sending the dates do it in the - or . format rather than using str_replace, but str_replace is a pretty fast function either way.

Comment: Oh crap, just realized there's an error in my code should be `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));` or `$date = strtotime(str_replace('/','.',$date))`;

Answer (score 1):

> They are formated in this way: 01/04/2011,08/04/2011

That is probably your problem: If these dates are supposed in April, you are using the european way of writing dates. `strtotime` expects american dates, so it's probably interpreting the month as the day, and the day of the month (which is also why it breaks if the day is greater than 12).

Wikipedia: [Date and time notation in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States)

Comment: Meh beat me to it by a minute =\ Oh well, +1. @op: As usual, when something doesn't work right reading the manual may help.

Comment: Yes, that's the same I thought, but what's the solution? Should I break them by score and them pull a new date? Seems a little bit dirty.

Comment: @Antonio you could change the format of the incoming dates. If that's not possible, a very clean approach would be [`DateTime::CreateFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) - if you have PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the day and the month mixed up. When you feed them to strtotime(), it is expecting the month to be the second number, not the first.

Comment: That's the problem, but do you know what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see strptime is the only php function to accept a date as a string, and a **date format**, with the returned array you can then generate a timestamp.

eg:

```
$timeArr = strptime($date_start ,"DD/MM/YY");
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $timeArr['tm_mon']+1, $timeArr['tm_mday'], $timeArr['tm_year']);
$date_start_form = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

or you could build the string directly, eg:

```
$timeArr = strptime($date_start ,"DD/MM/YY");
$date_start_form = sprintf(%d-%d-%d, $timeArr['tm_year'], $timeArr['tm_mon']+1, $timeArr['tm_mday']);
```

Although thinking about it you could just treat the incomming date as a string that needs to be rearranged, and ignore the fact its a date, eg:

```
$timeArr = explode($date_start ,"/");
$date_start_form = sprintf(%d-%d-%d, $timeArr[2], $timeArr[1], $timeArr[0]);
```

Comment: This should return an array, not solving the issue AFAIK

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more detail.  I suggested strptime as it was the function that would accept the date format. You can use the array to generate a new string

Answer (score 0):

That is timezone issue. strtotime takes it into account. You may set the correct one with

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

or whichever prior to strtotime call. See the [list of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: Nah, changing the timezone doesn't work, look at my answer.  If changing the timezone worked then you'd have very weird behavior in say a forum or whatever where users could set their own timezone.

Comment: @Phoenix: if you look at strtotime manual, it clearly says "This function will use the TZ environment variable (if available) to calculate the timestamp." Though, you are right, probably TZ does not affect the date format used for parsing.

Comment: Yeah, it uses the timezone to determine the offset from UTC to derive the number of seconds from 00:00:00 Jan 1, 1970 UTC.  Essentially, it assumes that the time/date given to strtotime is a time/date from the currently set timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use php=>5.3, it might worth looking at [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function.
For your case it may be implemented like:

```
$date = "08/04/2011";
$date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date);
$timestamp = $date_object->getTimestamp();
```