# PHP date parsing

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a custom Moodle plugin that somebody else wrote. A user enters a date in the plugin and that date gets recorded against a learning activity.

Originally I had a problem where the plugin would mistake some dates and get confused between AU(UK) date format and US date format. I fixed that problem using the solution from here ([How to make strtotime parse dates in Australian (i.e. UK) format: dd/mm/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444820/how-to-make-strtotime-parse-dates-in-australian-i-e-uk-format-dd-mm-yyyy)).

But now a weird error pops up every now and then where certain dates (notably July 2nd, 2015) gets it's *year* and *day* transposed. So `02-07-2015` gets recorded as `15-07-2002`.

It doesn't appear to be an AU vrs US date thing because that should just flip the day and month, not the *year*. Also, it only happens with that specific date. `01-07-2015` and `03-07-2015` work fine.

What's even more frustrating is that I can't reproduce this on our staging server. The problem only occurs in our production server, even though they are both running the same code and same version of Moodle.

What I can share of the code is how I am processing the date, which is...

```
$date[$i] = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date[$i]));
```

This has got me wondering if there could be some PHP setting that could be causing this. Or something else I'm over looking?

FYI, the production server is maintained by a paid hosting provider and I don't have access to the php.ini file (but I do on staging).

Has anyone has issues like this? Or can you suggest where I could start looking to find the problem?

Comment: plz xplain with code

Comment: So how exactly you parse the date and how do you check it's parsed incorrectly?

Comment: Like I said, somebody else wrote this plugin, so it's not mine to share. Also there's a LOT of code, and if the bug is in the code, I have no idea which bit is relevant.

Comment: hey have you checked current datetime and timezone on your both server.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with how I parse the dates, but I don't think that's where the problem is. @Bugfixer the timezones are slightly different (one is Melbourne, the other is Perth), but both are in AU.

Comment: @LucienStals - thats really weird thing never happened with me.

Comment: There is a an [answer here for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime/6239010#6239010)

Answer (score 0):

try to adjust your format in date function like below, in place of using str_replace

```
if $dat = '2015-07-17';
$date= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dat));
```

OR

```
$date= date('d:m:Y', strtotime($dat));
```

OR

```
$date= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dat));
```

OR

```
$date= date('m-d-Y', strtotime($dat));
```